# speed up google app script (already optimized ?)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write my first google app script, inside a google spreadsheet. Like many people I have a problem with the script execution speed. I spent quite a bit of time trying to do this.

I understood that it was necessary to avoid google API calls as much as possible (`.getDataRange(), .getRow(), getActiveSpreadsheet()`) and to work with arrays.

Depending on the sheet were the user is, different scripts are executed.
The code written for the sheet "0- FORMULAIRE" is too slow. I want to optimize it. In this sheet my script take 1s to execute each time.
Is there anything else I can do?

I searched for myself, but now I have no more ideas ...
Any help will be welcome...
Thank you very much!

The code to optimize :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
var nom_feuille_actuelle = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();  
// 
if (nom_feuille_actuelle == "0- FORMULAIRE") {
  // --- Fonction 2 ---
  var debut_colonne_cases = 17
  var colonne_statut = 23
  //
  var cellule_actuelle = s.getActiveRange();
  var ligne = cellule_actuelle.getRow();
  var colonne = cellule_actuelle.getColumn();
  if (debut_colonne_cases <= colonne <= debut_colonne_cases + 3) {  
    var matrice = s.getRange(ligne,debut_colonne_cases,1,7);
    var valeurs_matrice = matrice.getValues();
    var valeur_cellule = valeurs_matrice[0][colonne - debut_colonne_cases];
    var valeur_cellule_colonne_plus_1 = valeurs_matrice[0][1];
    var valeur_cellule_colonne_plus_3 = valeurs_matrice[0][3];
    if(colonne == debut_colonne_cases) { 
      if (valeur_cellule == "VRAI") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["VRAI","FAUX","FAUX","FAUX",,,"Réussi"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      }
      else if (valeur_cellule == "FAUX") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","FAUX","FAUX","FAUX",,,"-------------------"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      };
    }
    else if(colonne == debut_colonne_cases + 1) { 
      if (valeur_cellule == "VRAI" && valeur_cellule_colonne_plus_3 == "VRAI") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","VRAI","FAUX","VRAI",,,"Souhaité"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      }
      else if (valeur_cellule == "VRAI") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","VRAI","FAUX","FAUX",,,"Echec"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      } 
      else if (valeur_cellule == "FAUX" && valeur_cellule_colonne_plus_3 == "VRAI") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","FAUX","FAUX","VRAI",,,"Souhaité"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      }
      else if (valeur_cellule == "FAUX") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","FAUX","FAUX","FAUX",,,"-------------------"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      };       
    }
    else if(colonne == debut_colonne_cases + 2) { 
      if (valeur_cellule == "VRAI") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","FAUX","VRAI","FAUX",,,"-- Précisez --"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
                                                            .setAllowInvalid(true)
                                                            .requireValueInList(["-- Précisez --", "1- Démarré", "2- Sous peu", "3- Lointain"], true)
                                                            .build());  
      }
      else if (valeur_cellule == "FAUX") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","FAUX","FAUX","FAUX",,,"-------------------"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      };
    }
    else if(colonne == debut_colonne_cases + 3) { 
      if (valeur_cellule == "VRAI" && valeur_cellule_colonne_plus_1 == "VRAI") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","VRAI","FAUX","VRAI",,,"Souhaité"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      }
      else if (valeur_cellule == "VRAI") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","FAUX","FAUX","VRAI",,,"Souhaité"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      } 
      else if (valeur_cellule == "FAUX" && valeur_cellule_colonne_plus_1 == "VRAI") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","VRAI","FAUX","FAUX",,,"Echec"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      }
      else if (valeur_cellule == "FAUX") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","FAUX","FAUX","FAUX",,,"-------------------"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      };          
    };
  };
}
```

The entire code for my function onEdit :

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
var nom_feuille_actuelle = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();  
// 
if (nom_feuille_actuelle == "0- FORMULAIRE") {
  // --- Fonction 2 ---
  var debut_colonne_cases = 17
  var colonne_statut = 23
  //
  var cellule_actuelle = s.getActiveRange();
  var ligne = cellule_actuelle.getRow();
  var colonne = cellule_actuelle.getColumn();
  if (debut_colonne_cases <= colonne <= debut_colonne_cases + 3) {  
    var matrice = s.getRange(ligne,debut_colonne_cases,1,7);
    var valeurs_matrice = matrice.getValues();
    var valeur_cellule = valeurs_matrice[0][colonne - debut_colonne_cases];
    var valeur_cellule_colonne_plus_1 = valeurs_matrice[0][1];
    var valeur_cellule_colonne_plus_3 = valeurs_matrice[0][3];
    if(colonne == debut_colonne_cases) { 
      if (valeur_cellule == "VRAI") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["VRAI","FAUX","FAUX","FAUX",,,"Réussi"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      }
      else if (valeur_cellule == "FAUX") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","FAUX","FAUX","FAUX",,,"-------------------"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      };
    }
    else if(colonne == debut_colonne_cases + 1) { 
      if (valeur_cellule == "VRAI" && valeur_cellule_colonne_plus_3 == "VRAI") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","VRAI","FAUX","VRAI",,,"Souhaité"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      }
      else if (valeur_cellule == "VRAI") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","VRAI","FAUX","FAUX",,,"Echec"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      } 
      else if (valeur_cellule == "FAUX" && valeur_cellule_colonne_plus_3 == "VRAI") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","FAUX","FAUX","VRAI",,,"Souhaité"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      }
      else if (valeur_cellule == "FAUX") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","FAUX","FAUX","FAUX",,,"-------------------"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      };       
    }
    else if(colonne == debut_colonne_cases + 2) { 
      if (valeur_cellule == "VRAI") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","FAUX","VRAI","FAUX",,,"-- Précisez --"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
                                                            .setAllowInvalid(true)
                                                            .requireValueInList(["-- Précisez --", "1- Démarré", "2- Sous peu", "3- Lointain"], true)
                                                            .build());  
      }
      else if (valeur_cellule == "FAUX") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","FAUX","FAUX","FAUX",,,"-------------------"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      };
    }
    else if(colonne == debut_colonne_cases + 3) { 
      if (valeur_cellule == "VRAI" && valeur_cellule_colonne_plus_1 == "VRAI") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","VRAI","FAUX","VRAI",,,"Souhaité"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      }
      else if (valeur_cellule == "VRAI") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","FAUX","FAUX","VRAI",,,"Souhaité"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      } 
      else if (valeur_cellule == "FAUX" && valeur_cellule_colonne_plus_1 == "VRAI") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","VRAI","FAUX","FAUX",,,"Echec"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      }
      else if (valeur_cellule == "FAUX") {
        var nouvelles_valeurs_matrice = [["FAUX","FAUX","FAUX","FAUX",,,"-------------------"]];
        matrice.setValues(nouvelles_valeurs_matrice);
        s.getRange(ligne, colonne_statut).clearDataValidations();
      };          
    };
  };
} 
//
//  
else if (nom_feuille_actuelle == "PARAMETRES") { 
  // --- Fonction 1 ---
  //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //var s = ss.getActiveSheet()
  //var s = ss.getSheetByName("PARAMETRES");
  var ligne = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getRow();
  var valeurs_colonne_A = s.getRange("A:A").getValues(); 
  var valeur_ligne_actuelle_colonne_B = s.getRange(ligne, 2).getValues(); 
  if (!isNaN(parseFloat(valeur_ligne_actuelle_colonne_B)) && isFinite(valeur_ligne_actuelle_colonne_B)) { // Vérifie si la valeur récupérée colonne B est bien un nombre ou pas
    for(var i = ligne; i < valeur_ligne_actuelle_colonne_B; i++){ 
      if(valeurs_colonne_A[i] == "hide") { 
        s.hideRows(i+1, 1); 
      }
      else { 
        s.showRows(i+1, 1); 
      }
    }  
  } 
};
};
```

Comment: Aren't you using `setValues()` many times? Or will it execute  only once?

Comment: setValues() are on each if statements, but finally, depending on the condition, it is executed only once....

Comment: I'd probably use [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) instead of the `if...else if` blocks, use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) instead of working with the activeRange and put the `setValues` and `clearDataValidations` out of the corresponding `else if` blocks (DRY principle), but I don't think any of this would have much effect on the performance.

Comment: I don't see any loops in your function, and I don't think the performance can be much improved, if you really need to set new row values and remove data validations every time there's an edit.

Comment: What is this? `if (debut_colonne_cases <= colonne <= debut_colonne_cases + 3) {`

Comment: Thank you very much for your replys ! @TheMaster sorry for the chain comparison, I didn't know that the chain comparison in javascript wasn't done like that. Calculuswhiz you are right. i will correct the 'getValues()'